# How to make a floating action button become a menu

Tags: android, menu, material-design, floating-action-button

I am trying to make this from the material design guidelines:

Could you tell me how to morph the fab into [the desired view](https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_11/assets/0B8v7jImPsDi-d09QRUZzVUdMSFk/components-buttons-fab-transition_card_01.webm)?

Comment: visit https://github.com/gowong/material-sheet-fab

Answer (score 4):

You can use this library to achieve that - [MaterialSheetLibrary](https://github.com/gowong/material-sheet-fab)

Comment: The library is not maintained and has only 1 contributor. I would like to make it as easy as possible on my own, but i ran into problems with the morphing..

Comment: Since it is open source you can always use the code from the library as a reference point to continue where you got stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the task into two steps

1. Add a Floating Action Button (FAB)
2. Add a Menu to the OnClick Handler for the button

Add the FAB to your XML layout. 
In the onClick method you can inflate a PopMenu, as shown here 
https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/android/android-popup-menu-with-examples

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, fab);
MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, popup.getMenu());
popup.show();
```

You still need to add some more code to get the animations. Hope this gets you started